# How to format a <div> inside a <table>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this:

[image]

And I want to get to something like this:

[image]

Here is my `html`:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="box">P</div></td>
        <td>My First Game</td>
        <td>100 / 250 plays</td>
        <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="box">P</div></td>
        <td>The best game ever if it was done.</td>
        <td>0 / 250 plays</td>
        <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="box">P</div></td>
        <td>Could be better but ya.</td>
        <td>0 / 50 plays</td>
        <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my `css` (scss):

```
table {
   border: none;
   height: 33px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
.box {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  background-color: #5AD427;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

A fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MattCamp/dzDm3/

My main concern is how to fix the boxes on the right side of each row. I can't seem to figure out how to format them so they don't have so much space around them and also to make the letter  in the middle centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/AmEtIPA/8/edit)

[image]

```
  <tr>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>My First Game</td>
    <td>100 / 250 plays</td>
    <td><a href="#">Players</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Duplicate</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Archive</a></td>
  </tr>
```

```
table {
  width:100%;               /**/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align:right;         /**/
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
}

table tr       {background:#fff;}
table tr:hover {background:#eff;}

table tr       td             {padding:5px 8px;}
table tr       td:first-child {border-left: 3px solid #fff;}
table tr       td:last-child  {border-right:3px solid #fff;}  
table tr:hover td:first-child {border-left: 3px solid #4EB2E2;}
table tr:hover td:last-child  {border-right:3px solid #4EB2E2;}

table tr td:nth-child(1){
  color:#fff;
  width: 33px;
  background-color: #5AD427;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2){
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks! How can I put some space between the green boxes?

Comment: @MattCamp by adding `border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 0 2px;` to `table`. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the div

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="box">P</td>
    <td>My First Game</td>
```

and then add vertical-align: middle to the .box css

Answer (score 0):

Put the box class on the td cell itself instead of on a div inside the td (remove the div entirely).  You're probably fighting cell padding, which is why you have so much whitespace around the box.

Look in to line-height and vertical-align CSS properties for the character positioning inside the box.

See fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/dzDm3/2/

```
<td class='box'>P</td>

.box {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #5AD427;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    line-height: 26px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/ absolute positioning should work but I'm not sure if I read your question right. Check this site out, it gives a good tutorial and explanation on divs inside tables.